# firebase cloud functions need Blaze plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I deploy my firebase function it gives me this error

> HTTP Error: 400, Billing account for project '114709772351' is not found. Billing must be enabled for activation of service(s) 'cloudbuild.googleapis.com,containerregistry.googleapis.com' to proceed.

I found we need to have a firebase blaze plan to use cloud functions with Node js 10. I don't want to use Node js 8 because it will be no longer support in the future.  I'm asking is there any way to send automatic push notifications for an app without using cloud functions or if I go to a blaze plan will it be charge me for just this one cloud function ? I just need to send a notification to all the users when I upload a new post in my app

Comment: "*is there any way to send automatic push notifications for an app without using cloud functions*" - start with a web search to discover options that might not involve Cloud Functions. Questions asking for offsite references to software or products are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: While you need to be on a paid plan to use Node 10, Cloud Functions comes with a pretty decent free tier. So be sure to have a look at the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) and do some back of the napkins calculations to see if you'll go over these or even approach them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as Community Wiki, based in information from the comments.

Indeed, for you to use Node.js 10, you will need to have a paid plan configured in your project - Blaze plan in this case. However, the Blaze plan comes with all the limits from the Spark plan that it's free included. So, if you calculate your usage, you can confirm if you will ended up staying within the free quotas - for example, you have up to 2 million invocations on Cloud Functions within the Blaze plan. You can get all the quotas and prices [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), including a calculator of how much would you be spending, so you can check better the quotas.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @sithumdilanga ! Please, consider accepting it, so the Community knows that this answer and the comments ended up helping you.

Comment: it shows that Container storage has Usage costs of $0.026/GB. So I wanted to know if I basic (test) function for stripe, will get charged for Container Storage?